# Grails - Including CAS client JAR dependency causes StackOverflowError, logging conflict?

Tags: grails

If I include `compile "org.jasig.cas.client:cas-client-core:3.3.3"` in my `BuildConfig.groovy`, I get a stack overflow as seen below.  If I change `compile` to `runtime` the error goes away, but I do have dependencies at compile time as well as runtime.

It looks like some kind of circular reference related to logging, and just getting a stack dump like this isn't helpful.  How would I fix it?

---

```
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:253)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:52)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:35)
    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:59)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:42)
    at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:253)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:52)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:35)
    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:59)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:42)
    at org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:253)

| Error Error executing script RefreshDependencies: null
```

Comment: Is there anything else in the stacktrace other than those lines repeated?

Comment: nope.  since it's an overflow, those same lines repeat all the way to the top of the stack trace (cut off in my copy/paste above)

Answer (score 1):

You may have multiple versions of log4j-over-slf4j in your dependency chain. If you run 'grails dependency-report runtime', you will see a list of libs that your app sucks in.

Using transitive=false will exclude all dependencies of the lib, but you could try 'exclude "log4j-over-slf4j"' as a more focused exclude if you have multiple slf4j versions in your dependency chain. E.g.,

compile("org.jasig.cas.client:cas-client-core:3.3.3") {
        exclude "log4j-over-slf4j"
}

Answer (score 0):

adding `transitive=false` made the error go away:

```
compile("org.jasig.cas.client:cas-client-core:3.3.3") {
        transitive=false
}
```

I'm not clear what I needed to exclude specifically, or how anyone could have figured that out from the stack overflow.